Azure Logic App Https connection over SSL using .crt & .key files
Implementing ADP API integration, their set-up document shows you how to add a .crt & .key file into Postman for URLs to send HTTPs requests over. - This is working fine in Postman https://developers.adp.com/learn/how-to-articles/make-your-first-api-call-using-postman-1#prerequisite (The Documentation for Postman set up)
I'm now trying to implement this in Azure Logic apps (Standard), however, this is where I am hitting issues. I have uploaded the .csr into the certificates in the Logic App and added the thumbprint to the WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES in the Configuration. However, this is not enough as I still get "proper client SSL certificate was not presented", which I believe is due to the .key not being passed over.
I have also tried combining the crs and key file into a .pki and had no luck with this either.
Can any shed any light on how I can send an HTTPs request in a logic app using  a .crt and .key file?

Try the following:
1- Upload Certificate Files:
Upload your .crt and .key files to Azure Key Vault or Blob Storage. Ensure that the Logic App has the necessary permissions to access these files.
2- Retrieve Certificate Files:
Use the appropriate connector (e.g., Azure Key Vault connector, Azure Blob Storage connector) in your Logic App to retrieve the .crt and .key files at runtime.
Retrieve the content of both files and store them in variables within your Logic App.
3- Configure HTTP Action:
Add an HTTP action to your Logic App to send the HTTPS request.
Configure the action to use the HTTPS protocol and provide the target URL.
Use the "Client Certificate" section of the HTTP action to specify the client certificate:
For the "Certificate" field, use the content of the .crt file retrieved earlier.
For the "Key" field, use the content of the .key file retrieved earlier.
